# javascript array as values in associated array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to build an associated array dynamically like this. 
How do I build it? With the following expected output?

"happy": [1,2,3,4,5], 
"angry": [6,7,8,9,10]

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var videos = [];

$('.header-video__media').each(function(i, elem) {
  var mediaElement = $(elem);
  var mood = mediaElement.attr('data-mood');
  headerVideo = new HeaderVideo({
    index:i,
    element: '.header-video',
    media: '.header-video__media',
    playTrigger: '.header-video__play-trigger',
    closeTrigger: '.header-video__close-trigger',
    nextTrigger: '.header-video__next-trigger'
  });
  videos.mood = mood;
  videos.push (headerVideo);
});
```

Comment: What kind of question is this ?

Comment: Is this question or answer?

Comment: Can you show us your source data?

Comment: Show us the source data if you want to build it up dynamically.

Comment: There are no associative arrays in JS.

Comment: videos.mood = mood will not work since videos is an array. Add what should be the expected output you want to your question

Comment: this is expected output."happy": [1,2,3,4,5], 
"angry": [6,7,8,9,10]

Comment: what is these values 1,2,3  inside happy and angry, how you decide to add value to happy or angry?

Answer (score 0):

In the JavaScript world associative array are represented by literal objects:

```
// declaration of a new literal object
var videos = {};

// test if the key is already setted or not
if(!videos.hasOwnProperty(mood)){
   // if not, initiate a new array 
   videos[mood] = [headerVideo];
}else{
   // if yes, add add the value to the existing array 
   videos[mood].push(headerVideo);
}
```